# How scrape text from webpage that requires interaction in r

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest

I am trying to scrape reviews from a webpage to determine word frequency. However, only partial reviews are given when the review is longer. You have to click on "More" to get the webpage to show the full review. Here is the code I am using to extract the text of the review. How can I "click" on more to get the full review?

```
library(rvest)

tripAdvisorURL <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g33657-d85704- 
Reviews-Hotel_Bristol-Steamboat_Springs_Colorado.html#REVIEWS"

webpage <-read_html(tripAdvisorURL)

reviewData <- xml_nodes(webpage,xpath = '//*[contains(concat( " ", @class, " 
" ), concat( " ", "partial_entry", " " ))]')

head(reviewData)

xml_text(reviewData[[1]])

[1] "The rooms were clean and we slept so good we had room 10 and 12 we 
didn’t use 12 but it joins 10 .kind of strange but loved the hotel ..me 
personally I would take the hot tub out it was kinda old..the lady 
that...More"
```

Comment: Have you looked into Rselenium?

Comment: Alternatively you can follow the link at the title to access full text. Look for links in the page with ShowUserReviews

Comment: Have you looked at Trip Advisor's Terms of Service/Terms & Conditions and `robots.txt` or do you just like putting others in harm's way?

Comment: I did not see their terms of service, @hrbrmstr. I am only using it for the purpose of practicing programming in R. I will turn to another website for scraping. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, you can use Rselenium together with rvest for more interactivity:

```
library(RSelenium)

rmDr <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome")

myclient <- rmDr$client
tripAdvisorURL <- "https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g33657-d85704-Reviews-Hotel_Bristol-Steamboat_Springs_Colorado.html#REVIEWS"
myclient$navigate(tripAdvisorURL)
#select all "more" button, and loop to click them
webEles <- myclient$findElements(using = "css",value = ".ulBlueLinks")
for (webEle in webEles) {
    webEle$clickElement()
}

mypagesource <- myclient$getPageSource()

read_html(mypagesource[[1]]) %>%
    html_nodes(".partial_entry") %>%
    html_text()
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for your help @Yifu. I am working on looping it for all the pages of reviews now.